# using regexp, how to find strings containing only uppercase or lowercase

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I need to check the entire string for case. and only print those with all uppercase OR lowercase.

Here's the code I've written.

```
import re

lower = 'abcd'
upper = 'ABCD'
mix = 'aB'
mix2 = 'abcD'
exp = re.compile("[a-z]{2,}|[A-Z]{2,}")

lower_m = re.findall(exp,lower)
upper_m = re.findall(exp,upper)
mix_m = re.findall(exp,mix)
mix2_m = re.findall(exp,mix2)

print(lower_m)
print(upper_m)
print(mix_m)
print(mix2_m)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `upper()` and `lower()` string methods, rather than a regex.

```
if string.lower() == string or string.upper() == string:
    print string
```

If only letters are allowed, also check that `string.isalpha()`.

If a regex is necessary, the problem with yours is that you don't check the entire string.

`exp = re.compile("^([a-z]{2,}|[A-Z]{2,})$")`

This will ensure that the entire string needs to fit the pattern, rather than just part of it.

Comment: Good point, though OP didn't specify that the string can only contain ascii letters.

Comment: i need to use either re.search, re.match or re.findall.

Comment: and the text i need to test is only letters, no numbers.

Comment: Feel free to accept it then.  I notice you've never accepted an answer on a question before, and you really should accept to help the next person with the same problem rather than posting a thank you comment (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why you need to use a regex, but anyway:

```
if re.match('[a-z]+$', text) or re.match('[A-Z]+$', text):
    # is all lower or all upper
```

Which simplifies to:

```
if re.match('([a-z]+|[A-Z]+)$', text):
    # is all lower or all upper
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
import re

st='''abcd
ABCD
aB
abcD'''

for line in st.splitlines():
    line=line.strip()
    if re.search(r'^[a-z]+$',line):
        print(line,'only lower')
        continue
    if re.search(r'^[A-Z]+$',line):
        print(line,'only upper')
        continue   
    if re.search(r'^[a-zA-Z]+$',line):
        print(line,'mixed case')
```