# How do I match all unicode lowercase characters in Python with a regular expression?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, unicode, python-re

I am trying to write a regular expression that would match Unicode lowercase characters in Python 3. I'm using the `re` library. For example, `re.findall(some_pattern, 'u∏ñKθ')`  should return `['u', 'ñ', 'θ']`.

In Sublime Text, I could simply type `[[:lower:]]` to find these characters.

I'm aware that Python can match on any Unicode character with `re.compile('[^\W\d_]')`, but I specifically need to differentiate between uppercase and lowercase. I'm also aware that `re.compile('[a-z]')` would match any ASCII lowercase character, but my data is UTF-8, and it includes lots of non-ASCII characters—I checked.

Is this possible with regular expressions in Python 3, or will I need to take an alternative approach? I know other ways to do it. I was just hoping to use regex.

Comment: You can use regex along with some python logic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using regexp, how to find strings containing only uppercase or lowercase](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18176190/using-regexp-how-to-find-strings-containing-only-uppercase-or-lowercase)

Comment: @fsimonjetz No, it doesn't answer on all non-ascii characters

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) package if using a third party package is acceptable.

```py
>>> import regex
>>> s = 'ABCabcÆæ'
>>> m = regex.findall(r'[[:lower:]]', s)
>>> m
['a', 'b', 'c', 'æ']
```

Comment: I'm generally wary of third party packages, but if I can access it through `conda`, which I can this specific package, it's worth the risk. It looks like that's going to be my best bet. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [regex module](https://pypi.org/project/regex/) that supports POSIX character classes:

```
import regex 

>>> regex.findall('[[:lower:]]', 'u∏ñKθ')
['u', 'ñ', 'θ']
```

Or, use the [Unicode Category Class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) of `\p{Ll}` or `\p{Lowercase_Letter}`:

```
>>> regex.findall(r'\p{Ll}', 'u∏ñKθ')
['u', 'ñ', 'θ']
```

Or just use Python's string logic:

```
>>> [c for c in 'u∏ñKθ' if c.islower()]
['u', 'ñ', 'θ']
```

In either case, beware of string such as this:

```
>>> s2='\u0061\u0300\u00E0'
>>> s2
'àà'
```

The first [grapheme](https://unicode.org/glossary/#grapheme) `'à'` is the result of an `'a'` with the combining character of `'̀'` where the second `'à'` is the result of that specific code point. If you use a character class here, it will match `'a'` and not the combining accent:

```
>>> regex.findall('[[:lower:]]', s2)
['a', 'à']
>>> [c for c in s2 if c.islower()]
['a', 'à']
```

To solve that, you need to account for that in more complicated regex patterns or [normalize the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16467479/normalizing-unicode):

```
>>> regex.findall('[[:lower:]]', unicodedata.normalize('NFC',s2))
['à', 'à']
```

or loop through grapheme by grapheme:

```
>>> [c for c in regex.findall(r'\X', s2) if c.islower()]
['à', 'à']
```

Comment: I appreciate the tip. I was trying to avoid using `.islower()` because the part of the problem I didn't reveal is that I'm looking for several specific combinations of character types, e.g., a single uppercase character followed by at least one lowercase character also allowing some special characters. That's why I specifically wanted a regular expression. I'll install and use the regex module. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to use PyPi `regex` library (although I'd urge to use it here since it supports POSIX character classes (like `[:lower:]`) and Unicode property classes like `\p{Ll}`):

```py
import re, sys
lower = '[{}]'.format("".join([chr(i) for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()]))
print(re.findall(lower, 'ABCabcÆæóżźę'))
# => ['a', 'b', 'c', 'æ', 'ó', 'ż', 'ź', 'ę']
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##JYwxDoIwFIZ3TvHC0teEdHF2UI9BGCoUeQZa8lqjxLh6By/gBdyMG3KuSnD9v@/7@yE0zq5ipK53HIBNBn7wSevOhmENIr/eCqFqx50OmKbq6MhiXjaMJGGegYAssLYHg3OoOn05WSpdZSRQDX9RkV8OURZSJj2TDchG1WQr3ba4sAzEZrvT@3K8j8/xNX2m9/chpIzxBw).

**Results**:

```py
['a', 'b', 'c', 'æ', 'ó', 'ż', 'ź', 'ę']
```

Answer (score 0):

I created the following Python script to get all of the lowercase letters according to the `islower()` string method, and [find the contiguous ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628333/converting-a-list-of-integers-into-range-in-python) to create a large character class regex that identifies all lowercase letters.

```
import itertools, re, sys

lowercaseOrdinals = [i for i in range(sys.maxunicode) if chr(i).islower()]

def ranges(i):
    for a, b in itertools.groupby(enumerate(i), lambda pair: pair[1] - pair[0]):
        b = list(b)
        yield b[0][1], b[-1][1]

lowercaseRegex = '['
for startRangeOrdinal, endRangeOrdinal in ranges(lowercaseOrdinals):
    if startRangeOrdinal == endRangeOrdinal:
        lowercaseRegex += chr(startRangeOrdinal)
    else:
        lowercaseRegex += chr(startRangeOrdinal) + '-' + chr(endRangeOrdinal)    lowercaseRegex += ']'

with open('lower.txt', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as fileObj:
    fileObj.write(lowercaseRegex)
```

The 872 character-long character class regex it produces that matches any lowercase unicode character is here:

```
[a-zªµºß-öø-ÿāăąćĉċčďđēĕėęěĝğġģĥħĩīĭįıĳĵķ-ĸĺļľŀłńņň-ŉŋōŏőœŕŗřśŝşšţťŧũūŭůűųŵŷźżž-ƀƃƅƈƌ-ƍƒƕƙ-ƛƞơƣƥƨƪ-ƫƭưƴƶƹ-ƺƽ-ƿǆǉǌǎǐǒǔǖǘǚǜ-ǝǟǡǣǥǧǩǫǭǯ-ǰǳǵǹǻǽǿȁȃȅȇȉȋȍȏȑȓȕȗșțȝȟȡȣȥȧȩȫȭȯȱȳ-ȹȼȿ-ɀɂɇɉɋɍɏ-ʓʕ-ʸˀ-ˁˠ-ˤͅͱͳͷͺ-ͽΐά-ώϐ-ϑϕ-ϗϙϛϝϟϡϣϥϧϩϫϭϯ-ϳϵϸϻ-ϼа-џѡѣѥѧѩѫѭѯѱѳѵѷѹѻѽѿҁҋҍҏґғҕҗҙқҝҟҡңҥҧҩҫҭүұҳҵҷҹһҽҿӂӄӆӈӊӌӎ-ӏӑӓӕӗәӛӝӟӡӣӥӧөӫӭӯӱӳӵӷӹӻӽӿԁԃԅԇԉԋԍԏԑԓԕԗԙԛԝԟԡԣԥԧԩԫԭԯՠ-ֈა-ჺჽ-ჿᏸ-ᏽᲀ-ᲈᴀ-ᶿḁḃḅḇḉḋḍḏḑḓḕḗḙḛḝḟḡḣḥḧḩḫḭḯḱḳḵḷḹḻḽḿṁṃṅṇṉṋṍṏṑṓṕṗṙṛṝṟṡṣṥṧṩṫṭṯṱṳṵṷṹṻṽṿẁẃẅẇẉẋẍẏẑẓẕ-ẝẟạảấầẩẫậắằẳẵặẹẻẽếềểễệỉịọỏốồổỗộớờởỡợụủứừửữựỳỵỷỹỻỽỿ-ἇἐ-ἕἠ-ἧἰ-ἷὀ-ὅὐ-ὗὠ-ὧὰ-ώᾀ-ᾇᾐ-ᾗᾠ-ᾧᾰ-ᾴᾶ-ᾷιῂ-ῄῆ-ῇῐ-ΐῖ-ῗῠ-ῧῲ-ῴῶ-ῷⁱⁿₐ-ₜℊℎ-ℏℓℯℴℹℼ-ℽⅆ-ⅉⅎⅰ-ⅿↄⓐ-ⓩⰰ-ⱞⱡⱥ-ⱦⱨⱪⱬⱱⱳ-ⱴⱶ-ⱽⲁⲃⲅⲇⲉⲋⲍⲏⲑⲓⲕⲗⲙⲛⲝⲟⲡⲣⲥⲧⲩⲫⲭⲯⲱⲳⲵⲷⲹⲻⲽⲿⳁⳃⳅⳇⳉⳋⳍⳏⳑⳓⳕⳗⳙⳛⳝⳟⳡⳣ-ⳤⳬⳮⳳⴀ-ⴥⴧⴭꙁꙃꙅꙇꙉꙋꙍꙏꙑꙓꙕꙗꙙꙛꙝꙟꙡꙣꙥꙧꙩꙫꙭꚁꚃꚅꚇꚉꚋꚍꚏꚑꚓꚕꚗꚙꚛ-ꚝꜣꜥꜧꜩꜫꜭꜯ-ꜱꜳꜵꜷꜹꜻꜽꜿꝁꝃꝅꝇꝉꝋꝍꝏꝑꝓꝕꝗꝙꝛꝝꝟꝡꝣꝥꝧꝩꝫꝭꝯ-ꝸꝺꝼꝿꞁꞃꞅꞇꞌꞎꞑꞓ-ꞕꞗꞙꞛꞝꞟꞡꞣꞥꞧꞩꞯꞵꞷꞹꞻꞽꞿꟃꟈꟊꟶꟸ-ꟺꬰ-ꭚꭜ-ꭨꭰ-ꮿﬀ-ﬆﬓ-ﬗａ-ｚ--------------------------------]
```

Additionally, the 839 character-long uppercase version of this regex is here:

```
[A-ZÀ-ÖØ-ÞĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİĲĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸ-ŹŻŽƁ-ƂƄƆ-ƇƉ-ƋƎ-ƑƓ-ƔƖ-ƘƜ-ƝƟ-ƠƢƤƦ-ƧƩƬƮ-ƯƱ-ƳƵƷ-ƸƼǄǇǊǍǏǑǓǕǗǙǛǞǠǢǤǦǨǪǬǮǱǴǶ-ǸǺǼǾȀȂȄȆȈȊȌȎȐȒȔȖȘȚȜȞȠȢȤȦȨȪȬȮȰȲȺ-ȻȽ-ȾɁɃ-ɆɈɊɌɎͰͲͶͿΆΈ-ΊΌΎ-ΏΑ-ΡΣ-ΫϏϒ-ϔϘϚϜϞϠϢϤϦϨϪϬϮϴϷϹ-ϺϽ-ЯѠѢѤѦѨѪѬѮѰѲѴѶѸѺѼѾҀҊҌҎҐҒҔҖҘҚҜҞҠҢҤҦҨҪҬҮҰҲҴҶҸҺҼҾӀ-ӁӃӅӇӉӋӍӐӒӔӖӘӚӜӞӠӢӤӦӨӪӬӮӰӲӴӶӸӺӼӾԀԂԄԆԈԊԌԎԐԒԔԖԘԚԜԞԠԢԤԦԨԪԬԮԱ-ՖႠ-ჅჇჍᎠ-ᏵᲐ-ᲺᲽ-ᲿḀḂḄḆḈḊḌḎḐḒḔḖḘḚḜḞḠḢḤḦḨḪḬḮḰḲḴḶḸḺḼḾṀṂṄṆṈṊṌṎṐṒṔṖṘṚṜṞṠṢṤṦṨṪṬṮṰṲṴṶṸṺṼṾẀẂẄẆẈẊẌẎẐẒẔẞẠẢẤẦẨẪẬẮẰẲẴẶẸẺẼẾỀỂỄỆỈỊỌỎỐỒỔỖỘỚỜỞỠỢỤỦỨỪỬỮỰỲỴỶỸỺỼỾἈ-ἏἘ-ἝἨ-ἯἸ-ἿὈ-ὍὙὛὝὟὨ-ὯᾸ-ΆῈ-ΉῘ-ΊῨ-ῬῸ-Ώℂℇℋ-ℍℐ-ℒℕℙ-ℝℤΩℨK-ℭℰ-ℳℾ-ℿⅅⅠ-ⅯↃⒶ-ⓏⰀ-ⰮⱠⱢ-ⱤⱧⱩⱫⱭ-ⱰⱲⱵⱾ-ⲀⲂⲄⲆⲈⲊⲌⲎⲐⲒⲔⲖⲘⲚⲜⲞⲠⲢⲤⲦⲨⲪⲬⲮⲰⲲⲴⲶⲸⲺⲼⲾⳀⳂⳄⳆⳈⳊⳌⳎⳐⳒⳔⳖⳘⳚⳜⳞⳠⳢⳫⳭⳲꙀꙂꙄꙆꙈꙊꙌꙎꙐꙒꙔꙖꙘꙚꙜꙞꙠꙢꙤꙦꙨꙪꙬꚀꚂꚄꚆꚈꚊꚌꚎꚐꚒꚔꚖꚘꚚꜢꜤꜦꜨꜪꜬꜮꜲꜴꜶꜸꜺꜼꜾꝀꝂꝄꝆꝈꝊꝌꝎꝐꝒꝔꝖꝘꝚꝜꝞꝠꝢꝤꝦꝨꝪꝬꝮꝹꝻꝽ-ꝾꞀꞂꞄꞆꞋꞍꞐꞒꞖꞘꞚꞜꞞꞠꞢꞤꞦꞨꞪ-ꞮꞰ-ꞴꞶꞸꞺꞼꞾꟂꟄ-ꟇꟉꟵＡ-Ｚ------------------------------------]
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this -

```
import re

a = re.findall('[^\W\d_]', 'u∏ñKθ')

for i in a:
    if i.islower():
        print(i)
```

`re.findall` finds all the UTF-8 characters, then filter it out with `.islower()` to check if they are lower case characters and then print it

Comment: no point using a for loop, when a simple list comprehension is more then suitable. I'm downvoting your answer because you down voted mine.

Comment: List comprehension is used when you want to build a list. Here, I am printing the values and not lists

Comment: Thanks! I simplified my problem to make it clearer. The full problem, and the reason I wanted to use regular expressions, was that I'm looking for specific combinations of character types. For example, an uppercase character followed by 1 or more lowercase characters or specific special characters. I initially wrote out all these rules in `lambda` functions when I became frustrated with Python's `re` library, but they are ugly, so I took a second pass. Thanks for the input, though!